# LoopBack Fields filter doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mysql, loopbackjs

I am trying to create app with loopback, my problem is fields filters. It does not work. It return all data from database. Im using mysql connector.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Dog) {
  Dog.observe('loaded', function doStuf(ctx, next) {
    Dog.find({fields: {breed: true}}, function(err, data) {
    });
    next();
  });
};
```

I want to return to client response like:

```
{
"breed": "labrador"
},
{
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs for loaded (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Operation-hooks.html), the loaded function lets you modify data before returning it to an operation. Your use of find() does nothing. I mean nothing relevant. You want to modify data itself. So try changing `ctx.data`. You can remove or add keys there.